# Optaplanner constraint streams join on List property

Tags: optaplanner

I'm rewriting some constraints from drools syntax to the new Constraint Streams API.  I prefer the Constraint Streams syntax, but I'm not sure how to replicate a certain technique I've used in Drools, which involves matching on each element of a list provided from a property of a PlanningEntity.

Like this simplified example:

```
rule "My Rule"
when
  $e = MyEntity(selected)
  $s = Map.Entry($k:key, $v:value) from $e.scores
then
  scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, (int)$k, (int)$v);
end
```

Is there a way to do this sort of matching with the ConstraintStreams API?  I can do something similar with groupBy, but I have to score by the sum off all scores for an entity rather than a separate match for each score.  I'd prefer to match each score separately for a cleaner score explanation.

Edit for more details.

Essentially I just want a flatMap() function in the constraintStreams API. My challenge is that I have a additional optional criteria that can be applied to each planningEntity by the user.  These criteria come with a level, weight, and scoring function.  I want to match each optional criteria separately, calculate the score function based on the selected entity and weight, then apply it to the given level (using a BendableScore).

Using groupBy, I can achieve a match of a planning entity with a list of it's optional criteria which can then evaluated and summed together.  But I'd like a separate match for each optional criteria in the score explanation.  e.g. instead of one match of a planning entity and it's 10 sub criteria, I'd want a flatmap of 10 matches with the planning entity and a single sub criteria.

I found that constraintStreams are unsuitable for my purpose anyway since I cannot control the Score level based one the matched entities when using the reward or penalize functions.  I will continue to use the drools syntax.

Comment: To allow match weighters to pick the score, I've created this issue: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-2257
Can you give an example of your use case why it needs that? I believe there are better ways, unless I am missing something.

Comment: Our application allows the user to add custom constraints to a solution.  Things like "if selected planningEntity has property X of type integer, penalize soft score level 3 for every point X>500."  The levels are passed in by the user so we need to be able to access them during runtime.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting! What kind of application is it? How many score levels do you support?

Comment: It's scheduling software that receives 3rd party bids for a number of tasks.  The bids have various attributes like cost, speed, quality, but also sometimes arbitrary attributes specific to certain suppliers.  The user can specify minimum/maximum values for arbitrary attributes for each task and order them by importance (e.g. speed is most important for one task, and cost for another).  We're using 10 soft levels of a bendable score, and users often submit multiple configurations to compare schedules with different priorities.

Comment: Very interesting use case for BendableScore, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples is a bit abstract to recognize what fits bests, and I hope `scores` doesn't have instances of OptaPlanner's `Score` class, but maybe `ifExists()` fulfills your needs.

```
f.from(MyEntity.class)
.filter(MyEntity::isSelected) // Obsolete if that is a null check on your planning var
ifExists(MyFact.class, equal(MyEntity::this, MyFact::getMyEntity))
```

Although it seems to a natural fit for `groupBy()`:

```
f.from(MyFact.class)
.groupBy(MyFact::getMyEntity, count())
.filter((myFact, count) -> count > 5)
.penalize(...)
```

ConstraintMatches wise for justification, please elaborate on your challenges.

Comment: I'm currently using groupBy, but what I'd really want is flatMap.  I want a match for each item in a list property on my planningEntity.  I could rewrite my data model so I could select from my sublist directly, but I'd prefer not to do that at this point and it was not needed with drools.  I found other limitations of the constraintStreams API that make it unsuitable for my purposes, so I'll stick with the drools syntax for now.

Comment: I updated the drools example to more clearly show what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @BrianBlonski `flatMap` (or flattening) is in our to investigate list. Thanks for the feedback. What other limitations did you run into? We're working on plugging all API gaps.

Answer (score 0):

One trick that you can use is to just collect the entire Constraint Stream and throw into `.penelizeConfig(..., collection)` because now you have left the boundaries of ConstraintStream and you can use Java Stream API to return the matchweight. Not sure if this helped you as I have never used BendableScore. More support in the ConstraintStream API is even better though.